# Project File Not Found while attempting build in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a solution that has 6 projects, some of which are in separate DevOps projects. I am attempting to setup a build pipeline in Azure DevOps and my repository is already located there. Regardless of location, I continue to get errors that the csproj file cannot be found for any of the projects. The build cannot continue without the csproj files (obviously).

I have tried to move the .SLN file to the root folder, inside the specific project file and still get this error. I have also looked at the relative paths in the .SLN and attempted to manually modify them without any change.

Additionally, I used the vanilla configuration for the build pipeline before attempting to change path locations etc.

Here is the structure of source control:
[Source structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX1EN.png)

The 6 projects highlighted yellow are included in this solution.

Here is the output errors from the build in DevOps:
[Output errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYBtF.png)

I also tried adding the locations explicitly without any luck. By default, the location path was just $/PermitInspector/PermitInspector which is the location of the .SLN file. (Which is where I started with the attempt to automate builds).

Any suggestions would be helpful and I would be happy to share additional information or screen grabs that might be useful, but this is all I can come up with so far.

Comment: What workspace does your build have mapped? What does the directory structure of the project on a machine where it builds properly look like? Does it match what's been synched to the build server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the path issues by applying path filters under the build configuration in DevOps. There is a single work space and 3 of the projects are located in a root folder within the work space and the other 3 projects were in a separate root folder. The main issue appeared to be that the solution file is located inside the second root folder so I had to explicitly define the path to the other project files. By default, the only mapped work space was to the location of the SLN file. Now if I can just get NuGet restore working for the sub-projects! Thanks again,

[Correct mapping that fixed the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mozdj.png)